# Can someone explain me how to dynamically allocate memory for a vectors of pointers

Tags: c++, memory, vector, dynamic, tree

Can someone please explain me the given code. I am not able to understand the purpose of using  `vector <treenode < int > * > child;`
It is creating a vector with name child but what is the point of using **treenode** in the declaration .
Also i have used templates in this problem(in case the information help)

```
class treenode
{
    public:
    int data;
                
    vector<treenode<int>*> child;
    treenode(T data)
    {
        this ->data = data;
    }
};
```

Comment: it's a `vector` (I assume a `std::vector`) of pointers to `treenode<int>`. I'd guess that the source code has a tree structure that is made up tree nodes that hold integer data. These tree nodes would be of type `treenode<int>`. If you need to keep track of some of the tree nodes, you could store pointers to those nodes in a `std::vector`. The `std::` which you may have seen means "belonging to the `std` namespace.

Comment: yes you are correct, Actually i want to ask why it has used "treenode"  in the declaration i.e. vector<treenode<int>*> child.                                                             Because the syntax for vector declaration is vector<int>*  vec_name

Comment: It's not.  You just declared a pointer to a vector of ints that way. WHat is decared in code is a vector of pointers to treenode... but it's odd as it assumes that treenode is template, See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector. For templated type  `template-name <parameter-list>` is the syntax of specifying type's name.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than post another comment, you may not know that templates can be defined in terms of other templates, to any level theoretically - but constrained by the limits of the machine. Eg `vector<T>` is a vector of objects with type `T`. But `T` itself can be a template.

In this case the vector template is itself a template. `treenode<int> *`.

Okay, you can have a `vector` of `int`, of `string`, of anything you like. In your example, the coders had a tree structure with nodes they called `treenode`. IMHO, it would make more sense to call nodes "branches" ( like the branches of a tree).

Anyway, vectors are often used to keep track of a list of things that need attention. Could be integers, parts of data structures, anything.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like incomplete code. It should be something like

```
template <class T>
class treenode
```

because `vector<treenode<int>*> child` is a template type `vector` with type parameter `treenode<int>*` and `treenode` must be template to allow template parameter `<int>`. I also question sanity of this code. If it describes a node of tree containing data of type T (which may be `int`), then

```
template <class T>
class treenode
{
public:
    T data;
                
    vector<treenode<T>*> child;

    treenode(T data)  // (or T&? or const T&? or T&&?)
    {
        this ->data = data;
    }
```

A `vector<treenode*>` in context of declaration `template <class T> class treenode` is a vector of pointers to `treenode<T>`.

Now consider following code. I added something useful to `treenode` to show off how you can allocate memory. To avoid confusion, a new type `Data` would serve as T instead of `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
// using namespace std;

template <class T>
class treenode
{
public:
    T data; // with using `namespace std;` this can be a problem, 
            // because there is `std::data`
   
    // treenode<T> is class containing this, so we can refer it 
    // just as treenode             
    std::vector<treenode*> child; 

    treenode(const T& d) : data(d)  
    // if you use data as argument name, 
    // you are shadowing treenode::data member
    {
    }
    
    void add_node(const T& d)
    {
        // here we create a pointer with value returned by new
        // treenode was initialized by d within new expression.
        child.emplace_back(new treenode{d});
    }
    
    ~treenode() {
        // vector contained raw pointers we allocated memory for.
        // this avoids leaks.
        for(auto& p : child)
            delete p;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Data {
    T value;
    
    Data(T v) : value(v) {std::cout << "Hello, data = " << v << std::endl;}
    ~Data() {std::cout << "Bye, data = " << value << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    // this is legal after C++17, template parameters can be deducted
    treenode a = {Data{42}}; 

    // It's same as this C++11 declaration
    //    treenode<Data<int>> a  = {42};
    
    a.add_node(34);
    
    return 0;
}
```

We can use a smart pointer instead, avoid usage of new

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class treenode
{
public:
    T data;
                
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<treenode>> child;

    treenode(const T& d) : data(d) {}
    
    void add_node(const T& d)
    {
        child.emplace_back(std::make_unique<treenode>(d));
    }
    
    ~treenode() { } 
    // no action needed,  pointers clean up after themselves!
};
```

Can you figure what it would do?

```
Hello, data = 42
Bye, data = 42
Hello, data = 34
Bye, data = 34
// a is getting destroyed.
Bye, data = 34
Bye, data = 42
```

Some Data died there. That's because this setup creates some temporaries of T = Data, Data was copied or moved and we didn't saw it. It's ok, if `T` of treenode is an `int`. For a complex type it can be ab issue, if our Data didn't have proper copy\move operations. Let's add constructors at least.

```
template <class T>
struct Data {
    T value;
    
    Data(const T& v) : value(v) 
    {std::cout << "Hello, data = " << v << std::endl;}
    
    // move constructor
    Data(Data&& v) : value(std::move(v.value))  
    {std::cout << "Moved data = " << v.value << std::endl; v.value = T{}; }
    // copy constructor
    Data(const Data& v) : value(v.value) 
    { std::cout << "Copied data = " << v.value << std::endl; }
    
    ~Data() {std::cout << "Bye, data = " << value << std::endl;}
};
```

Now we can see copy operation:

```
Hello, data = 42
Copied data = 42
Bye, data = 42
Hello, data = 34
Copied data = 34
Bye, data = 34
Bye, data = 34
Bye, data = 42
```

FOr simple, "flat" types this can be fine, copy and move operation  are equal for them. But for some containers creation of temporary  object which we never will use again and then making a copy of allocated memory is expensive. It's agreed that "move" operation would transfer ownership of allocated resources to target object and modify the source so it will not deallocate them. Source object would become invalid after that.We must have add support for move and copy of T to our `treenode` class.

```
template <class T>
class treenode
{
public:
    T data;
                
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<treenode>> child;

    treenode(const T& d) : data(d) {}
    treenode(T&& d) : data(std::move(d)) {}
    
    void add_node(const T& d)
    {
        child.emplace_back(std::make_unique<treenode>(d));
    }
    
    void add_node(T&& d)
    {
        child.emplace_back(std::make_unique<treenode>(std::move(d)));
    }
    
    ~treenode() {
    }
};
```

Now  everything adds up:

```
Hello, data = 42   // we created Data(42)
Moved data = 42    // its value was moved
Bye, data = 0      // it was destroyed.

Hello, data = 34
Moved data = 34
Bye, data = 0

Bye, data = 34    // a is being destroyed
Bye, data = 42
```

Having two `add_node` implementations is excessive. In some case, where more than one argument is involved, it may lead to exponential explosion in amount of declarations. All we need is to use single [perfect forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

```
template <class V = T>
void add_node(V&& d) {
    child.emplace_back(std::make_unique<treenode>(std::forward<V>(d)));
}
```

This would lead to operation like this:

```
Data c {63};
a.add_node(c);
```

to cause a copy creation:

```
Hello, data = 63
Copied data = 63
```

As a last touch would need to define a default constructor for a tree node,  a  move constructors as well, to finish its design to the [Rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). A copy constructor may or maybe not correct  thing to do, it depends if we want allow to create a copy of tree, just of the node's value, or disallow it at all.

```
template <class T>
class treenode
{
public:
    T data;
                
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<treenode>> child;

    treenode(const T& d) : data(d) {}
    treenode(T&& d) : data(std::move(d)) {}
    
    treenode() : data() {}
    
    // treenode(treenode&& other): 
    //  data(std::move(other.data)), child(std::move(other.child)) {}
    treenode(treenode&& other) = default;
    
    // would not copy children, std::unique_ptr is not copyable
    treenode(const treenode& other) : data(other.data) {}
    
    // it's default because we move all  members.
    treenode& operator=(treenode&& other) = default;
        
    // copies data's value, doesn't alter children
    treenode& operator=(const treenode& other) 
    { this->data = other.data; return *this; }
        
    template <class V = T>
    void add_node(V&& d) {
        child.emplace_back(std::make_unique<treenode>(std::forward<V>(d)));
    }     
    
    ~treenode() = default;
};
```

Data needs its special members too:

```
template <class T>
struct Data {
    T value;
    
    Data(const T& v) : value(v) 
    { std::cout << "Hello, data = " << v << std::endl;}
    
    Data(Data&& v) : value(std::move(v.value)) 
    { std::cout << "Moved data = " << v.value << std::endl; v.value = T{}; }
    Data(const Data& v) : value(v.value) 
    { std::cout << "Copied data = " << v.value << std::endl; }
    
    Data() : T() {}
    ~Data() {std::cout << "Bye, data = " << value << std::endl;}
    
    Data& operator=(Data&& other) = default;
    Data& operator=(const Data& other) = default;
};
```